# JUnit 5 Dynamic file path for @CsvFileSource

Tags: junit5, parameterized

I use the below to access a csv file in my paramaterized JUnit5 test but is there any way to dynamically provide this csv file or a different file path to the location of the csv file?

```
@CsvFileSource(resources = "/testDataFile/testData.csv" , numLinesToSkip = 1, delimiter =  ';', encoding = "UTF-8")
```

In other words can I dynamically update "/testDataFile/testData.csv"?

I want a way to dynamically pass in the file path for my csv file so it is not a hardcoded location or file name.

Comment: Could you explain why your `resources`/`files` aren't known at compile time? Or are they known and you don't want them "hardcoded" for a different reason?

Comment: They are known I would just like the ability to set the path dynamically. For example if I want to use a command line parameter to specify the input file to use for my test data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is not possible. In general, the value for an annotation must be a constant expression. And the `@CsvFileSource` API doesn't support dynamic/programmatic control over the supplied value(s), at least to my knowledge.

Two possible custom solutions:

1. Create an [`@ArgumentsSource`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-sources-ArgumentsSource) and a corresponding `ArgumentsProvider`, based on [`CsvArgumentsProvider`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/main/junit-jupiter-params/src/main/java/org/junit/jupiter/params/provider/CsvArgumentsProvider.java) (which is non-public).
2. Create an [extension](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions) that dynamically creates the CSV file(s) specified as `resources`/`files` in `@CsvFileSource`.